# Fetching unique list of object arrays

Tags: java

How do I fetch unique list of object arrays in below code:

```
    import java.util.*;

    class t1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Object[] o1 = new Object[] { null, "abc@aaa.com", "ENG", "775778435", 1};
            Object[] o2 = new Object[] { null, "abc@aaa.com", "ENG", "775778435", 1};

            List<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<Object[]>(); 
            result.add(o1); 
            result.add(o2); 

            // The above result list is coming from some DB & I cannot change the structure of above script. 
            // Now, I need to remove the duplicates from this result list meaning I need to find duplicates from the objects within the list.
            // I tried below code but it still prints duplicates. Any help???

            Set<User> setResult = new HashSet<User>();
            User userInfo = null;

            for (Object[] userData : result) {
                userInfo = new User((String)userData[0], (String)userData[1], (String)userData[2], (String)userData[3], (Integer) userData[4]);
                setResult.add(userInfo);
            }

            Iterator it = setResult.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Object o = it.next();

                User u = (User) o;
                System.out.println("non-duplicate = " + u.getEmail());
            }

            // Expected result: non-duplicate = abc@aaa.com
            // Actual   result: non-duplicate = abc@aaa.com getting printed twice i.e. duplicate not getting removed!
        }
    }

    class User {
        public String firstName;
        public String email;
        public String language;
        public String productCode;
        public int status;

        public User() {         
        }

        public User(String fName, String userId, String lang, String productCode, int status) {
            this.firstName = fName;
            this.email = userId;
            this.language = lang;
            this.productCode = productCode;
            this.status = status;
        }   

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getLanguage() {
            return language;
        }

        public void setLanguage(String language) {
            this.language = language;
        }

        public String getProductCode() {
            return productCode;
        }

        public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
            this.productCode = productCode;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(int status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int fNameHash = 0;
            int lNameHash = 0;
            int emailHash = 0;
            int langHash = 0;
            int productCodeHash = 0;

            if (this.firstName != null) {
                fNameHash = this.firstName.hashCode();
            }

            if (this.email != null) {
                emailHash = this.email.hashCode();
            }

            if (this.language != null) {
                langHash = this.language.hashCode();
            }

            if (this.productCode != null) {
                productCodeHash = this.productCode.hashCode();
            }

            return (fNameHash + lNameHash + emailHash + langHash + productCodeHash + this.status);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(obj != null && obj instanceof User) {
                User temp = (User) obj;

                if (this.firstName != null && temp.firstName != null && this.firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.firstName) 
                   && this.email != null && temp.email != null && this.email.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.email) 
                   && this.language != null && temp.language != null && this.language.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.language)
                   && this.productCode != null && temp.productCode != null && this.productCode.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.productCode)
                   && this.status == temp.status) {             
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }   
    }
```

My expected result is to print abc@aaa.com only once but its getting printed twice!!

Can any one tell me how to correct this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the firstName value that is null for both objects. Because of this the equals() method return false and both your objects are considered distinct by the `Set`.

Try changing your equals and hashcode with the following:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;

    User user = (User) o;

    if (status != user.status) return false;
    if (email != null ? !email.equals(user.email) : user.email != null) return false;
    if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(user.firstName) : user.firstName != null) return false;
    if (language != null ? !language.equals(user.language) : user.language != null) return false;
    if (productCode != null ? !productCode.equals(user.productCode) : user.productCode != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (language != null ? language.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (productCode != null ? productCode.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + status;
    return result;
}
```

Best way is to have equals and hashcode generated from your IDE as suggested in another answer.

Comment: Name can be null & that's the requirement. How do I fix it?

Comment: If I remove null check for fName in equals method, it gives null pointer exception....How do I do it then?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `User.equals` will predictably return `false` because both instances have `null` `firstName`s:

> ```
> if (this.firstName != null && temp.firstName != null && this.firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.firstName)
> ```

As a result, even though they have identical `hashCode`, it's merely treated as a collision rather than a match, since `equals` is broken.

Try correcting that :-) Replacing the logic with something like...

```
firstName == temp.firstName || firstName != null && firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.firstName)
```

... should work ;-)

You can see a fully-working version [here](http://ideone.com/hXq3t).

---

As an aside, you forgot to ever assign `lNameHash` in `User.hashCode`.

Comment: Can you please help me in correcting it? Can you please provide me the sample code?  If I remove null check for fName in equals method, it gives null pointer exception....How do I do it then?

Answer (score 1):

Both your `equals` method and your `hashcode` method are implemented incorrectly.

- Your `equals` method returns `false` when both objects have `null` members.
- Your implementation of `hashCode` can return different hash codes for some objects which compare equal.

You must provide correct implementations of `equals` and `hashCode` to be able to use your objects in a `HashSet`.

Comment: ...Can you please help me in correcting it...If I remove null check for fName in equals method, it gives null pointer exception....How do I do it then?

Comment: @Mike: What IDE do you use? Almost all decent IDEs can give you a working implementation of equals and hashCode. Generate them, then adjust them if necessary (e.g. adding the case insensitivity). Remember that every change you make to equals must be reflected in hashCode too.